# How can I pass args to a curl request executed via boost::process:child?

Tags: c++, rest, curl, boost

I'm able to execute a http POST request using curl via `boost::process::child` by passing the entire command line. However, I would like to pass the arguments via `boost::process::args` but I cannot get it work.

This works:

```
const std::string cmdDiscord = "curl -X POST https://discord.com:443/api/webhooks/1234567890 -H \"content-type: application/json\" -d \"{\"content\": \"test\"}\"";

boost::process::child c(cmdDiscord);                         // this works
boost::process::child c(boost::process::cmd = cmdDiscord);   // strangely, this doesn't work
```

I want to use `boost::process::args` but this fails:

```
std::vector<std::string> argsDiscord {"-X POST",
                                      "https://discord.com:443/api/webhooks/1234567890",
                                      "-H \"content-type: application/json\"",
                                      "-d \"{\"content\": \"test\"}\""};

boost::process::child c(boost::process::search_path("curl"), boost::process::args (argsDiscord));
```

The error is `curl: (55) Failed sending HTTP POST request` which is quite a vague error message. I couldn't find any examples calling curl. Does anyone have any suggestions on getting this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
std::vector<std::string> argsDiscord {"-X", "POST",
                                      "https://discord.com:443/api/webhooks/1234567890",
                                      "-H", "content-type: application/json",
                                      "-d", "{\"content\": \"test\"}"};
```

Since command interpretators pass arguments like `-X POST` are two arguments, not one.

The double quotes are a shell syntax as well. The shell interprets (removes) them during command line expansion.

Alternatively curl accepts adjacent values in short options (without space)

```
std::vector<std::string> argsDiscord {"-XPOST",
                                      "https://discord.com:443/api/webhooks/1234567890",
                                      "-H", "content-type: application/json",
                                      "-d", "{\"content\": \"test\"}"};
```

Comment: Thanks - I've split "-X POST" into two arguments and now I'm getting a different error:

`{"message": "Cannot send an empty message", "code": 50006}`

The message format is correct so i have no idea why it's failing:

`"-d", "{\"content\": \"test\"}"};`

Comment: This is the server response message. It does not accept the JSON you send.

Comment: Yes, I realise this but sending the full command line works fine, it just fails when I use `boost::process::args`. I have output the args in script and they are all correct - I just can't see how boost is interpreting these internally.